# Network error related with permissions?

Tags: contacts

When I log in with the username of certain users and try to edit a field and save, I get a Network Error. However, If I log in with another users or as the admin, I can edit the field with no problem at all. Same computer, same profile to edit.

Why this network error depending on the user?

Thanks!

[image: Network error when saving content]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Javascript error.  You may want to check out the [Troubleshooting Javascript](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) forum post for help on this.